# How can I get every date (UTC) from the last 30 days in PHP?

Tags: php, date

How can I get an array with all the dates in UTC (YYYY-MM-DD) from the last 30 days?`
I tried to make a loop / array but I didnt succeed and only got every day in the last 30 days but the month/year didnt change..

Does someone have an idea? :))
Thanks alot!

Comment: Do show how you tried to do it. Also do you mention UTC as in "today" is defined by "now" in UTC or some other meaning? Since UTC doesn't mean much with dates.

Comment: This is not a code writing service. You show what you've done to attempt this yourself, and we'll (maybe) try help fix it. Anything else is simply "do my job/homework for me".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
for($i=1; $i<=30; $i++)
 {
   echo $days_ago = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-'.$i.' days',strtotime(date('Y-m-d'))));
   echo '<br/>';
 }
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted! Thanks alot!! :))

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php    
$d = array();
for($i = 0; $i < 30; $i++) 
$d[] = date("d", strtotime('-'. $i .' days'));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do date time modify minus one day.

```
$dates = array();
$DateTime = new DateTime();
for($i = 0; $i < 30; $i++) {
    $DateTime->modify( "-1 days" );
    $dates[] =  $DateTime->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

Each iteration you subtract one day, and then save the formatted date, and repeat.